# JavaScript Alert Not Working After Inserting Objects Into Arrays

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I created an array, and after inserting some objects into it, the alert() function ceases to work. Code as shown below.

```
var map;
var ship_icon = "http://i.imgur.com/ubs6Vp5.png";
var markerArray = [];
function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    addmarker(LocationA, 'Stuff');
    addmarker(LocationB, 'More Stuff');
    addmarker(LocationC, 'Most Stuff');
    alert("This alert() should be shown by the browser.");
}

function addMarker(location, name) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        title: name,
        icon: ship_icon
    });
    markerArray.push(marker);
}
```

Comment: Hi. Check console errors.

Comment: You declare object as 'markerArray' and you are inserting objects into addmarker.
 function initialize(){
     var markerArray = [];

     markerArray (LocationA, 'Stuff');
     markerArray (LocationB, 'More Stuff');
     markerArray (LocationC, 'Most Stuff');
     alert("This alert() should be shown by the browser.");
 }

Comment: `var markerArray` defined in `initialize()` function not available for other functions (variable scope). Put outside your function to make it global.

Comment: Use developer tools (console) to check for errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping it is breaking somewhere your method `addmarker()` that's why alert is not popping up in your browser,

```
function insertItem() {
    var itemArray = [];
    itemArray.push('FIrst');
    itemArray.push('Second');
    alert('in');
}

insertItem();
```

Comment: This is not really an answer !

Comment: the question is completely got change now i am seeing some google map api which has been added to the code, previously it was just simple java-scripts point.

Comment: Used console.log(). Found out the error. Thanks for referring me to such a powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be a difference between your function call `addmarker(LocationA, 'Stuff')` and function declaration addMarker(location, name).

`addmarker` is not defined.